# How to make a live date display using Python and tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, date, tkinter, clock

I'm trying to make an info center and I need to add a live date display, so every day it adds another day to it, if a month passes it would add a month to it. How would I do it?

I've googled and still have no idea, I know how to display it but no clue how to make it automatically update. would it be possible to do it like this below?

```
def tick():
    time_string = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    clock.config(text=time_string)
    clock.after(200, tick)

root = Tk()

clock = Label(root, font=("none", 50, "bold"), bg="#000000", fg="#910000", bd=5, relief="ridge")
clock.grid(row=0, column=0)

tick()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is fine. If you want to display months and days, you can use `datetime` module instead:

```
from datetime import datetime

def tick():
    now = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    clock.config(text=now)
    clock.after(200, tick)
```